# How can I make select2 read only and not disabled?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jquery-select2

I write a view page with asp core and use select2 for my combo box .when use disable this line code work good:

```
$('select').prop("disabled", true);
```

but it disable and not readonly. i want readonly. in readonly value save but in disable valu not save and posted null value to controller. in select2 document with this(

```
$('select').select2('readonly',true);
```

OR

```
$('select').prop('readonly',true);
```

can readonly. but it can not work for me. why?? :-(

Comment: Use `<input type='hidden' name='myselect'` after the `<select name='myselect'>`

Comment: please use google translate

Comment: i put hidden input as you said but it not work,and combo item list blow the combo container and do not , it is my code in my view page on asp.net core:

Comment: <select id="Ostanid" name="Ostanid" asp-items="Model.ostan_combo" calss="form-control" style="width:100%">
                <input type='hidden' name='Ostanid'>
                <option value="0">----</option>
            </select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem with select2 readonly.

First, add this CSS:

```
select[readonly].select2-hidden-accessible + .select2-container {
    pointer-events: none;
    touch-action: none;
    opacity:0.6;
    cursor:no-drop;
}
```

Now to do readonly, I must add this jQuery code:

```
$("#Ostanid").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

And to remove the readonly attribute, I must add this:

```
$("#Ostanid").removeAttr("readonly");
```